# 404 not found , the requested URL <<url name>> not found on this server in wordpress

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I recently installed wordpress , I am facing issues when I try to change the  permalinks format ,

when I change the permalink from default to day and time

```
 Default    http://127.0.0.1/?p=123
 Day and name   http://127.0.0.1/2015/03/16/sample-post/
```

the link generated does't working , it gives the same `error 404` all the 
time ,

```
 The requested URL /2015/03/16/post-5-problem/ was not found on this server.
```

But when the permalink type was default this works perfectly.

I found some solutions which are

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

Module rewrite already enabled
```

Another solution is to **change the mode permissions of .htaccess file to 666(giving write permission to wordpress of .htaccess file) before change the permalink from default to some other type ,**

```
sudo chmod 666 /address_of_.htaccess
```

i checked the .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but the above seems to be correct , the above included by the wordpress itself

Both the solutions does't seem to work , is there any other thing do I have to change to enable the permalink options ?

Comment: What is the content of .htaccess file in your WordPress directory?

Comment: Try to add AllowOverride All into Directory section of Apache configuration for your document root P.S. of course, restart your apache after that ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If it is a fresh install of web server it is possible that .htaccess rules are not allowed by default. To fix that, edit you httpd.conf (usually it is in /etc/apache2), find

```
<Directory "path/to/your/document/root">    
    # ....

     AllowOverride None

    # ....

</Directory>
```

and change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Then restart your web server and try again.

Comment: for ubuntu users , the file name is apche2.conf       # yes , thank you  , i forgot that , i recently re installed the apache .

Comment: The default value for AllowOverride in CentOS7 & httpd is `None`.  In my case, the option wasn't specified in the conf file.  I added `AllowOverride All`, restarted httpd and wordpress friendly URLs finally work.

Comment: Ubuntu 20 path: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Reset your desired permalink from wordpress admin area and add this code in htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, check with blog posts and pages.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can go to preferences -> services & ports and you need to check enabled ssl for Apache

It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because your webserver cannot find the file, and it's not passing the request to Wordpress.

You need to add rewrite rules for your Wordpress, and instructions for that depend on your webserver software (Apache, nginx, etc).

Example with nginx:

```
location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Which literally means: try to open "/2015/03/16/post-5-problem/" in filesystem first, if it doesn't exist try to add a slash, if that doesn't help pass the request to index.php (which is Wordpress main file) with the arguments.

Enabling rewrite module is not enough, you have to add rewrite rule(s).

Comment: could you be more specific on where to add rewrite rules and instructions , and i am using apache .