# The requested URL xxxxx was not found on this server

Tags: .htaccess

I've already added the .htaccess with this content

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
`# END WordPress`
```

and the same problem appeared whenever i change the permalink structure , i've also read a question that was asked here before and changed (AllowOverride None) to (AllowOverride ALL) in the httpd.conf and the same problem appeared again..

Comment: Did you restart apache after making the conf change?

Comment: Rather than implying a question could you please state it explicitly, and perhaps you could give a link to the question you mention so that we can get more context?

Comment: @PanamaJack yes i did ..

Comment: @AndrewMorton sir here is the link
 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074376/404-not-found-the-requested-url-url-name-not-found-on-this-server-in-wordp)

Comment: @PanamaJack can you help me  ?